# android: LocationListener running permanently

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, locationlistener

I have an app which will start sending location data to a remote server, when I press a button. I am using `LocationListener` since I want to send the location points if a certain distance or time threshold is reached.

I want the `LocationListener` to send data to the server as long as the phone is on and the button is not pressed back to shut it down.

How can I do that?

How can I have the `LocationListener` to run continuously as long as the phone is on - even if I am not running the app which activated the location listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run this in a service. Are you sure you want to do this though? This will drain the battery fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well that's why I keep a button for activating/deactivating the service. I want to user to do something else while he needs to update the server with his location data.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416141/a-background-sensor-data-collector-in-android/4416626#4416626