# Android: Collect sensor information in the background

Tags: java, android, background, sensors, android-sensors

I am wondering if it is possible to create an application that collects sensor information in the background, e.g.: use the camera to take a picture, access the accelerometer and obtain readings, when a screen gesture is performed (and the x and y coordinates for it), etc.

From what I have seen so far this is only limited to when you are in the application. Is there a way to do this in the background, e.g.: accelerometer for gait analysis?

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416141/a-background-sensor-data-collector-in-android . Did not flag whole question as duplicate because in same question you mention detecting screen gesture from a service, which is not cover in link.