# how to stop the user from quitting the app android

Tags: android

My application sends an sql insert query everytime the telephone is tilted at more than 45°

I need either to stop the user from quitting the application or have it still running in the background so that it still sends the queries

basically I need the application to be running all the time, any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html). This will run in the background executing the SQL inserts while leaving the user free to interact with their phone and answer calls. Remember to keep in mind battery usage and CPU resources while it is running.

Another common technique is to add a [status bar notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) while the service is running. This informs the user that the app is still running in the background, and allows them to bring a relevant activity back to the foreground by selecting it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is for sure - do **not** prevent the users from quitting the application. There is, however, a wakelock that can keep the processor on despite being out of the app, using the wakelock flag `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. Look into services and wakelock.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) for more information on PowerManager and WakeLock, and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more information on Services.  [This link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html) is also pretty helpful regarding a demo on how to use a Service, and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039555/how-to-get-an-android-wakelock-to-work) displays how to properly setup a WakeLock (although you'd want to replace `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK` with `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` for your purpose).

Comment: haha thanks I checked out the link demo on how to use the service just before seeing your answer through google, thanks for recommending it , it was very helpful.