# To get the Gps value frequently android?

Tags: android, gps

Hai i develop a application for getting the Gps value its woking fine.But i faced some problem

**problem**

1.when mobile is screen locked

2.when mobile is swtched off into switch on

3.when mobile display light is off

**MyRequirements**

Anytime i want to get the gps value ,except the mobile is switched of

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
networkLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (networkLoc != null) {
double l = (double) (networkLoc.getLatitude());
double lng11 = (double) (networkLoc.getLongitude());
latituteField1.setText(Double.toString(l));
 longitudeField1.setText(Double.toString(lng11));
 } 
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
        this
    );
    }
   @Override
  protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
        this
   );
   }
@Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
lat1 = (double) (networkLoc.getLatitude());
lng1 = (double) (networkLoc.getLongitude());
  latituteField1.setText(Double.toString(lat1));
  longitudeField1.setText(Double.toString(lng1));      
  }
  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

  }
   @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

    @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Disenabled provider " + provider,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the device powers down the screen after some time and than also the CPU. If this happens you will not get any more updates from the GPS. To prevent this behavior you need to aquire a WakeLock.

Wakelocks are described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

And here is another article on WakeLocks: [How to get an Android WakeLock to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2039555/1127492)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimerTask` Class and Android's `Alarm` Class.  In the `TimerTask's` Run method keep fetching gps data on particular interval ( suppose on every minute ). And use `Alarm` Class for closing `LocationListener` Class & Opening on every hour. This way your application will work very efficiently. I used same for my application. For Auto start on Switch on Mobile, you can use Android Services.

TimerTask's Example is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/SchedulingaTimerTasktoRunRepeatedly.htm).
AlarmManager's Example is [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html).

Comment: ya , I have developed Location Tracker Application for same purpose, for Auto Start, you can use Android Service.

Comment: if i use service class is it always run,ie when screen lock,when mobile backlight off?

Comment: am trying the above example but the toast print one time only

Comment: That is because you haven't called it again & again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7273/discussion-between-micro-and-lucifer)