# PowerManager newWakeLock.acquire() not working as expected

Tags: android, powermanager

I want my app to keep the CPU running but turn the screen off to minimise power wastage.

Previous posts on this subject suggest the following approach:

```
    mPm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock =  mPm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, Constants.WAKE_LOCK_TAG);

    mWakeLock.acquire();    //keep CPU running, turn screen off
```

The manifest contains:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

In my innocence I expected that on acquiring the lock the screen would go off immediately but nothing happened.
The earlier posts I have read never seem to overcome this problem, did anyone succeed?  Is there anything else I must do?

Comment: The screen shouldn't go off immediately for partial wake locks, it should go off at its normal time out rate (eg after 30 seconds). Is that what is happening or is the screen staying on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an Android WakeLock to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039555/how-to-get-an-android-wakelock-to-work)

Comment: @t0mm13b, it's not a duplicate of this issue. At best, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

It would be more efficient in another way to use this within the `onCreate` method of the activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

That is a better way to use wake-locks in a efficient manner.

Comment: **Don't forget to clear the flags** in the `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: OP didn't want to know how to keep the screen on, but rather how to turn it off. Correct answer, wrong question.

Comment: @miNde I do not think there's a need for that, as Android manages that automatically when the activity gets destroyed. The Android runtime is handling the lock, when the app is in foreground, wakelock is handled, otherwise the runtime release the lock automatically if not in the foreground or destroyed! :)

Answer (score 2):

The wake lock does not turn off the screen.  Normally, when the screen goes off, your application pauses because the CPU is put to sleep.  If you have `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`, your app will continue to run and the CPU will be active even when the screen goes off (due to auto or manual sleeping).  Only use this if you really need to continue processing data after the screen is off.  You mention you are concerned about minimizing power usage, acquiring a wake lock of any kind can cause waster power.  It is wise to follow this warning from the [`PowerManager` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

> Device battery life will be significantly affected by the use of this
>   API. Do not acquire PowerManager.WakeLocks unless you really need
>   them, use the minimum levels possible, and be sure to release them as
>   soon as possible.

So it is good idea to evaluate why you think you need a wake lock for your task.  If you think it is too save power, it isn't.

Comment: Thanks to A--C and iagreen who have suggested something I can test.

Comment: Seems very likely I misunderstood how wake lock would work. Yes, I do want to keep the CPU running when the screen goes off so that the app can react to user shaking the device.

Comment: As you and A--C expected, the screen does go off(time out) correctly. The device then has to be powered up and the lock screen cleared before the app can continue. No "shakes" were registered by the app during the black-out. There are a couple of things I must try but I have a feeling that I'm tackling this the wrong way. I was hoping that by using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK I could keep the CPU running and still responsive to the accelerometer even while the lock screen is in place. A vain hope.