# Android WakeLocks not working

Tags: android-wake-lock

Right at the `acquire()` it fails.  Eclipse doesn't say what the error was. It just stops the execution on my emulator and gives me that "Class File Editor"  "Source not found" display.

```java
public class MyAppActivity extends Activity {

    private PowerManager pManager;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          allocStructs();
    }

    private void allocStructs() {

        // I've tried this with "getBaseContext()" and with "this"
        // same results.  I get a pManager and a wakeLock
        // Then it crashes when I attempt to acquire
        pManager = (PowerManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                               Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pManager.newWakeLock(       
                                    PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "full");
    }

    public void onWakeLockButtonClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        if (!checked) {
            return;
        }
        if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.acquire();    // fails here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the logs say?

Comment: Which log?  My "LogCat" filtered for my App doesn't say anything.  I clear it just before I cause the failaure, then I cause the failure, and the LogCat is empty.

Comment: What is this "Class File Editor" "Source not found" ? Screen ? Where is `allocStructs()` called ? Post more of your code. Edit : add @user if you want _user_ to be notified of your comment

Comment: Well I attached more source code, now I no longer get the "Class File editor Source not Found Screen".  Now it simply stops at some line of code within the WakeLock handler.  I can't see any indication of what the error was or why it stopped.  This is my main entry point class for my App.

Comment: Post your logs with no filters. Do you `release()` someplace ?

Comment: My LogCat filtered by my App showed nothing.  I guess I should have looked at the unfiltered LogCat.  Maybe it did say something about permission.  Anyway once I put the try ... catch then I got the info I neeeded.  Well next time I'll be able to figure out the problem faster.  Thx anyway

Comment: accept your answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

OK I got my answer and am embarassed.  The quick answer is I didn't get the permission for Wake Locks in the manifest.

I had read the part that you need to get the wakelock permission but I thought in the debug emulator you may not need it.  Or it may get settled just by pressing .  Then by the way it was stopping I thought it was a crash, not a permission violation.  So I added this:

```java
    try {
         wakeLocks.acquire();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return;
    }
```

And sure enough it was a permission violation.  This link told me how to add the permission to my manifest.

[How to get an Android WakeLock to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039555/how-to-get-an-android-wakelock-to-work)

I couldn't figure out how to add the permission thru those menus, but I added this line to the xml source directly.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Then it works.