# Type of wakelock for waking cpu

Tags: android, wakelock

I have got an alarm manager and I am working with some tasks in background with alarm managers. I use wakelock for waking CPU in order to finish my background work which causes the error below. I have searched and found that a type of wakelock must be specified and I shouldn't use `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP`. What should I use instead?

My code:

```
private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
public static void acquirWakeLock(){
    if(wakeLock!=null){
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    PowerManager pm=(PowerManager) KITILApplication.getappContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
//Error is below line  
wakeLock=pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP|PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"aqs_wake_lock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}
public static void releaseWakeLock(){
    if(wakeLock!=null)
        wakeLock.release();
    wakeLock=null;
}
```

My Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.<init>
```

Answer (score 1):

checkout the official documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Answer (score 0):

`PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` is not a valid wake lock level.
Valid parameters according to `validateWakeLockParameters()` method are:

```
PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
FULL_WAKE_LOCK
PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK
DOZE_WAKE_LOCK
DRAW_WAKE_LOCK
```

So, instead of `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` exactly one wake lock is intended to be used, for example:

```
newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "aqs_wake_lock");
```

See also:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock

[How to get an Android WakeLock to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039555/how-to-get-an-android-wakelock-to-work)